# How to disable the titlebar close, minimize and zoom buttons in an NSViewController on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsviewcontroller

How do I disable/enable the titlebar close, minimize and zoom (red, yellow and green) buttons in an NSViewController - preferably from Objective-C/Swift.

I have searched the Storyboard properties but not found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The close, minimize and zoom buttons are owned by the window. They are automatically enabled and disabled. Set `styleMask` of the window to enable or disable the buttons. You can enable and disable the buttons in the XIB.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. you can.  Using appearance section windows controller you can do the changes.

[image]